# Socket.io : install chat based on socket.io on LAMP shared hosting

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, livechat

I want to create a realtime chat application, It was decided to implement after I purchased a shared hosting plan. I have installed npm and node on the shared hosting via nvm from [this tutorial](http://vinyll.scopyleft.fr/installing-a-custom-version-of-node-on-a-shared-hosting/) which is running..

but before I take a next step, i wanted to ask that is it safe to implement socket.io on this server? and will my application be compatible to that environment? if not, is there other work around to implement text based live chat on my project, or a way I can increase my compatibility?

Comment: Generally, if you can run npm you are 100% compatible. Unlike other languages, each project written in node.js install their own libraries inside the `node_modules` folder. This means the ONLY thing you have to worry about is what version of node you're running. Library incompatibilities don't exist in node projects.

Comment: well I have latest nom running on my server

Comment: do you know any way I can use socket.io on the server side?

Comment: As a client or a server?

Comment: got it done, thanks man!